# Using a named capture groups causes a different match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given Regex: `^(Start\.)?(.+?)(\.|\.\2)?(End)?$`

Test Input: `Start.Word.WordEnd`

I get `Word` for Group "2":

[image]

However if I change the regex to also include a name for the captured group, I get a different result:

Regex: `^(Start\.)?(?<capturedGroup>.+?)(\.|\.\2)?(End)?$`

capturedGroup is `Word.Word`

[image]

This is in .NET 4.7.2 (I also did the test in https://dotnetfiddle.net/ with the same result). Links:

first case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o33G6Y

second case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4zJuaQ

I tested this in https://regex101.com/ (set as PHP) and I get the expected result (both are `Word`), so I expect this to be a .NET issue? Please help.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe `\2` isn't matching capture group "2" because now it's called "capturedGroup".

Comment: The named group has ID 4 in this pattern. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341857/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [.NET `Grouping Constructs` regex docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions):

> Named matched subexpressions are numbered consecutively from left to right after matched subexpressions.

So, your pattern groups are parsed in this order:

```
^(Start\.)?(?<capturedGroup>.+?)(\.|\.\2)?(End)?$
 ^---1---^ ^-------- 4 --------^^---2---^ ^-3-^
```

When debugging, you may check the real group numeric IDs:

[image]

You just need to either use the named group backreference, `\k<capturedGroup>`, or use `\4` instead of `\2` (which is not that intuitive, so I'd rather you use the former solution).

- `^(Start\.)?(?<capturedGroup>.+?)(\.|\.\k<capturedGroup>)?(End)?$` - [Demo 1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28Start%5C.%29%3F%28%3F%3CcapturedGroup%3E.%2B%3F%29%28%5C.%7C%5C.%5Ck%3CcapturedGroup%3E%29%3F%28End%29%3F%24&i=Start.Word.WordEnd)
- `^(Start\.)?(?<capturedGroup>.+?)(\.|\.\4)?(End)?$` - [Demo 2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28Start%5C.%29%3F%28%3F%3CcapturedGroup%3E.%2B%3F%29%28%5C.%7C%5C.%5C4%29%3F%28End%29%3F%24&i=Start.Word.WordEnd)

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the fact that \2 matches the content from the 2nd set of parentheses in the expression wich was modified with and now it cannot match it.

Maybe because it is named and you would have the same name in two groups.

Comment: Yes. this is indeed the case.
I changed the regex to `@"^(Start\.)?(?<capturedGroup>.+?)(\.|\.\k<capturedGroup>)?(End)?$` and it worked.
I guess in .NET you can't use numbered backreferences if it is a named group.
I tried this in Regex101 (php) and there you can still use numbered references:
https://regex101.com/r/MbVqHT/1/